# Crash while freeing memory

Tags: c, crash

I have an application which is used to modify content of a pdf file. Once the required changes are made , i save the file and quit the application. During this process i would like the clear the memory that has been assigned to the pdf file. The code is as given below:

```
    for (i32 i = 0; i < job_state->PDF_IList_len; i++) {
        if(IList[i].PIL_ImageData.PDH_DataPtr.PDH_PathName)
            free (IList[i].PIL_ImageData.PDH_DataPtr.PDH_PathName);
        if(IList[i].PIL_DependentImages)
            free (IList[i].PIL_DependentImages);
    }
    job_state->PDF_ImageList = NULL;
    job_state->PDF_context = NULL;
    free (IList);
```

job_structure is a data structure to save info about the file. 
`PDH_Pathname` is the temp directory where the details of the pdf is stored.

My application always crashes at

```
free (IList[i].PIL_ImageData.PDH_DataPtr.PDH_PathName);
```

I have noticed that whenever it crashes,the value for free `(IList[i].PIL_ImageData.PDH_DataPtr.PDH_PathName)` cannot be evaluated(thats what the debugger says).

If the for loop is commented out,  there is no crash observed. Please let me know what can be the issue.

Comment: You could post where and how many times do you alocate those resources :/

Comment: You tagged this C++, but the code has calls to `free` :(

Comment: i am sorry.. this part of the code is in C

Comment: This resource has been allocated only once while launching the application with the file. The point is that it doesnt crash for file sizes less than 2048mMB .

Comment: `malloc` and `free` are perfectly valid C++ code, though there are certainly good arguments for preferring `new` and `delete` when possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Als' answer to use valgrind, it's probably worth setting your pointers to `NULL` after you've freed them:

```
for (i32 i = 0; i < job_state->PDF_IList_len; i++) {
    free (IList[i].PIL_ImageData.PDH_DataPtr.PDH_PathName);
    IList[i].PIL_ImageData.PDH_DataPtr.PDH_PathName = NULL;
    free (IList[i].PIL_DependentImages);
    IList[i].PIL_ImageData.PDH_DataPtr.PDH_PathName = NULL;        
}
```

`free()` doesn't set pointers to `NULL`, it only releases the memory stored there. Since you're testing the value of the pointer against zero to determine whether it needs to be freed, not setting the pointers to `NULL` could be causing a double free if this code is called twice (or if anything inside `IList[]` points to a structure also encountered later in the `IList[]`).

As per a comment, I've also removed the check against NULL before the free (as Joshua Green points out, `free(NULL)` is perfectly safe).

Comment: There's no reason to test a pointer against `NULL` before freeing it -- `free(NULL)` is a NOP.  Setting it to `NULL` after `free`ing it is, of course, the safest policy.

Answer (score 5):

Given the code that you have shown it is not possible to say anything about the root cause because:

- Your code does not show how the allocation was done on the faulting pointer.
- Nor does it show where all(could be lot many places) the said pointer was used.

The second one is a bit tricky because the pointer could have been passed to n control paths where it could be `free`d again or gets corrupted and understandably it is impossible to provide all of that in here as a part of the Question.

Given the above your best bet is to use a memory profiling tool like **Valgrind** on Unix/Linux systems or **Rational Purify** On Windows. Once you run your application with these, they will exactly point you out the root cause of the issue.